UWP RadialController (Dial) loses RotationChanged event
I use the Microsoft Dial in my UWP application to rotate an object and confirm a your textposition.
For this purpose, I use the RotationChanged and ButtonClicked events.
Now it happens that while the dial is in use (rotation), no more RotationChanged events occure in the app. This happens several times a day and is not reproducible. The ButtonClicked event still works!
As a workaround, the battery of the dial must be removed and replaced.
After that, the dial works again without any problems.
Details:
The DIAL menu is not needed, so it is suppressed.
I use the MVVM pattern and
initialize the RadialController in the ctor
and on leaving a viewmode the RadialController will be disposed.
On ControlAcquired event I reinitialize the RadialController like in the ctor.
I didn't always do that, but hoping it would improve the situation. But it didn't.
Does anyone know this behavior? How can this happen and how can I prevent it?
Best regards

I would "attach" any devices at startup; and keep them "attached" until the app was shut down; disposing them at that time; instead of "breaking" working connections every time a view changes; creating side effects.

Thanks for the tip, I'll try it out right away.
I'm going to abandon my original approach of initializing a RadialController in each ViewModel. Instead, I'm going to put a RadialControllerService singleton instance into my Dependency Container. In future, I'll only keep one connection to the RadialController, which I'll only use when needed or not!
I'll keep you updated...
